# How to Add A User To A Database In Standby / Read-Only Mode In Sql Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, permissions

I have a database which is in standby / read-only mode in my reporting server. But, I can not add a new user to this database. How can i add a new user to this database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if the database is part of logshipping. As the database in secondary server will be in Read-only/standby state. ALtering the database directly will not be allowed.

Identify the primary server and add the user there. This will move to your read-only secondary.

Edit : 1

Make sure the logins exist in both the servers.

Answer (score 0):

If it is SQL Login and not Windows Login you might want to create the login (user) on the replica with the same SID, that will assure permissions are replicated as well.

```
CREATE LOGIN login_name WITH Password = 'strong_password', SID = 0xSome_value
```

You can get the SID from the primary instance by querying table `sys.server_principals`.

```
Select name, sid From sys.server_principals Where name = login_name
```

Answer (score -2):

Use bellow commands:

ALTER DATABASE database_name ONLINE

Or try this will also works.

RESTORE DATABASE  WITH RECOVERY